# import classes when class declaration in another file - typewriter

Tags: c#, typescript, typewriter

I'm using typerwriter extension to create ts file corresponding to c# file, but there is some variables from type that declared in another file so I have to add import statement.

to do so, I want to get all the classes name that in this file and add import only if class name isnt in this list.

in this example BDTO in another file.

```
public class ADTO
{
    public uint id { get; set; }
    public uint editionId { get; set; }
    public BDTO mask { get; set; }
}
```

tst code:

```
 string Imports(Class c, File f)
{
    IEnumerable<String> classes = f.Classes.Select(p=> p.name);

    IEnumerable<Type> types = c.Properties
        .Select(p => p.Type)
        .Where(t =>((!t.IsPrimitive  || t.IsEnum) && !classes.Contains(t.name)))
        .Select(t => t.IsGeneric ? t.TypeArguments.First() : t)
        .Where(t => t.Name != c.Name && t.Name != "DbGeography")
        .Distinct();
    return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, types.Select(t => $"import {{ {t.Name} }} from './misc';").Distinct());
}

$Classes(*DTO)[
$Imports

export interface $Name {
    $Properties[
    // $LoudName
    $name: $Type;]
}]
```

this adding: `$Imports` instead of: `import {BDTO} from './misc'`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I think it is because the method can only take the one parameter, of type `Class`.

This example shows another way of solving the problem:
https://github.com/frhagn/Typewriter/issues/270